# Error is using EJB object

Tags: ejb-3.0

I have defined an EJB class - GetTransactionDataForMercury. Please find the sample code below:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class GetTransactionDataForMercury {

@EJB
private BusinessLocal business;

private Long historyId = null;

public GetTransactionDataForMercury(){
    super();
}

public void getHistoryForMercury() {
    try {
        historyId = getConfigHistoryId("QueryDslConfig");

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        notifier.error("Error Occured  -- > "+exception);
    }

}

public Long getConfigHistoryId(String requestType){
    notifier.info(" Processing QueryDslConfig " );
    Long historyId = null;
    BaseEntity entity = null;
    Long transactionStartTime = null;
    Long transactionEndTime = null;
    ConfigEntity configEntities[] = null;
    Query query = null;

    try{
        transactionStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notifier.info(" Going to Query  " );
        notifier.info("Business object created : " + business);
        List<BaseEntity> entities = business.query(new QueryFactory(requestType).create());
        notifier.info(" No. of entities fetched  " + entities.size());

        historyId = Long.parseLong(configEntities[0].getConfigId());
            notifier.info("History Id stored : " + historyId);

    }catch(Exception exception){
        transactionEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notifier.error("Error Occured  -- > "+exception.getMessage());
    }
    return historyId;
}
```

BusinessLocal is an EJB interface that is implemented by an EJB class - BusinessSLSB. I am facing a null error at the following line :

```
notifier.info("Business object created : " + business);
```

I need to know why is the EJB object coming as null? Is there any problem in creating the EJB class - GetTransactionDataForMercury?

Please suggest!

Comment: Your sample code seems to be incomplete the field `notifier` does not exist in it and so this class should never compile. You are hiding exactly that information that might lead to your error.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. I thought `notifier` was null. How do you instanciate/access the `GetTransactionDataForMercury` class?

Comment: Actually, a scheduler calls this particular file `GetTransactionDataForMercury`. Its not instantiated explicitly. The scheduler refers to a config xml that contains the following lines 
`<timertask>
 <timerName>HistoryForMercuryTimer00</timerName>
 <task>
     <name>HistoryForMercuryTask00</name>
     <timer>HistoryForMercuryTimer00</timer>
     <hour>*</hour>
     <minute>00</minute>
 <task>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.ejb.GetTransactionDataForMercury</task>
 </task>
</timertask>`

Comment: @San You might not be instantiating the class directly, but presumably the underlying scheduler is instantiating the class directly.  That won't work: you have to let the EJB container create the object.  You do that be performing a JNDI lookup, or injection the EJB into another managed object (e.g., a servlet);

Comment: @bkail : Thanks for that input..I will look for any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SLSB is not implementing any @Local or @Remote interfaces.
As such it is probably not being initialized properly by JBoss and is not injected with its dependencies.